# minikube start did not start minikube when kept the command in AWS EC2 location /etc/rc.d/rc.local

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, minikube

I want
`minikube start`
to run in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` as this script executes after everytime ec2 instance starts.

It is failing to start minikube when kept in `rc.local` but when I execute it as non-root user, it works.

Any help is appreciated to make it work from **rc.local** script

**Update:**
I've added `minikube start --force --driver=docker`
This time, it says:

```
E0913 18:12:21.898974   
10063 status.go:258] 
status error: NewSession: 
new client: 
new client: ssh: handshake failed: 
ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], 
no supported methods remain.

Failed to list containers for "kube-apiserver": 
docker: NewSession: new client: new client: 
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, 
attempted methods [none publickey],
```

no supported methods remain StackOverflow

etc etc

Comment: you can try this: `minikube delete && rm -rf ~/.minikube && minikube start`. Minikube "store" previous configuration so it might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I've created minikube with ssm-user. But rc.local executes as root user. Hence it could not start minikube.. I've added code snippet to switch to ssm-user in rc.local script to start minikube. This worked.